Cant proxy requests to docker container on a server running plesk
I tried setting up a fastapi application with docker (docker extension for plesk) on my server that runs with plesk.
this is my dockerfile
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /code/app

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["fastapi", "run", "app/main.py", "--port", "8000", "--proxy-headers"]

I deactivated automatic port mapping and mapped port 8000 to 8000. I added a docker proxy rule on the domain which i can then also see in the nginx.conf for this domain.
nginx.conf
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

server {
    listen <server-ip>:443 ssl;
    http2 on;

    server_name example.com;
    server_name www.example.com;
    server_name ipv4.example.com;

    ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfLZG53k;
    ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfLZG53k;

    client_max_body_size 134217728;

    access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log";
    error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/proxy_error_log";

    root "/var/www/vhosts/space.com/example.com";

    #extension performance-booster begin
    # Additional directives added by Plesk Optimization Settings

    # Additional directives added by Plesk Optimization Settings
    #extension performance-booster end

    #extension sslit begin

    #extension sslit end

    #extension letsencrypt begin
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs;

        types { }
        default_type text/plain;

        satisfy any;
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;

        location ~ ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge.*/\. {
            deny all;
        }
    }
    #extension letsencrypt end

    #extension sectigo begin
    location ^~ /.well-known/pki-validation/fileauth.txt {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/pki-validation/ {
        root /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs;

        types { }
        default_type text/plain;

        satisfy any;
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;

        location ~ ^/\.well-known/pki-validation.*/\. {
            deny all;
        }
    }
    #extension sectigo end

    #extension docker begin
    location ~ ^/.* {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    #extension docker end

    error_page 400 "/error_docs/bad_request.html";
    error_page 401 "/error_docs/unauthorized.html";
    error_page 403 "/error_docs/forbidden.html";
    error_page 404 "/error_docs/not_found.html";
    error_page 500 "/error_docs/internal_server_error.html";
    error_page 405 "/error_docs/method_not_allowed.html";
    error_page 406 "/error_docs/not_acceptable.html";
    error_page 407 "/error_docs/proxy_authentication_required.html";
    error_page 412 "/error_docs/precondition_failed.html";
    error_page 414 "/error_docs/request_uri_too_long.html";
    error_page 415 "/error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html";
    error_page 501 "/error_docs/not_implemented.html";
    error_page 502 "/error_docs/bad_gateway.html";
    error_page 503 "/error_docs/maintenance.html";

    location ^~ /error_docs {
        root "/var/www/vhosts/space.com";
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/(plesk-stat|awstats-icon|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat) {
        auth_basic "Domain statistics";
        auth_basic_user_file "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/pd/d..httpdocs@plesk-stat";
        autoindex on;

        location ~ ^/plesk-stat(.*) {
            alias /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/statistics/$1;
        }

        location ~ ^/awstats-icon(.*) {
            alias /usr/share/awstats/icon/$1;
        }

        location ~ ^/(.*) {
            alias /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/statistics/$1;
        }
    }

    location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/space.com/web_users/$1/$2;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    }

    location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    }

    index "index.html" "index.cgi" "index.pl" "index.php" "index.xhtml" "index.htm" "index.shtml";

    disable_symlinks if_not_owner "from=/var/www/vhosts/space.com";

    add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;

    include "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/conf/vhost_nginx.conf";
}

server {
    listen <server-ip>:80;

    server_name example.com;
    server_name www.example.com;
    server_name ipv4.example.com;

    client_max_body_size 134217728;

    access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/proxy_access_log";
    error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/proxy_error_log";

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

in my proxy_error_log i get this

 2024/06/24 10:34:30 [error] 3358953#0: *53 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: <ipadress>, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8000/", host: "example.com"
2024/06/24 11:14:32 [error] 3366602#0: *7026 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: <ipadress>, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8000/", host: "example.com"
2024/06/24 12:43:11 [error] 3384011#0: *24303 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: <ipadress>, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8000/", host: "example.com"
2024/06/24 13:18:33 [error] 3420358#0: *32497 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: <ipadress>, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8000/", host: "example.com"

the domain is secured by an ssl certificate from letsencrypt tested also with ssllabs.
i can access the domain like http://example.com:8000 but when i use https://example.com:8000 i get this error
 Error: write EPROTO 140577310899976:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../../../src/third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:

and in the docker logs i get the following

INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
WARNING:  Invalid HTTP request received.
WARNING:  Invalid HTTP request received.

when using http oder https without port i get a gateway timeout
i also cant curl within the server environment.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix that ? Any help would be very much appreciated!
the image runs perfectly local but not in the server environment tried to adjust the dockerfile to run like that:
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--proxy-headers"]

also didnt work
i tried to use a different port... that didnt work
restarted nginx multiple times
tried also with additional nginx directives in the apache & nginx nothing changed

0.0.0.0 is a special IP address that means "all interfaces".  It's important to use it in Docker to tell a server where to listen (as in your final CMD line) but it doesn't make sense to include it in a URL, like in your proxy_pass line.  Where is the Nginx proxy running?  How did you start the involved container(s)?

Thanks for the reply David! The nginx proxy is running on the server its installed as an extension in plesk and so is docker, i started the container in the docker extension but also tried it via cli. When i click on docker proxy rules which is an option for the domains i can then create a rule and this then gets inserted into the nginx.conf as seen in the file above.
